# Why does VSCode debugger always show node imports as undefined?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6

The VSCode debugger always shows imports as undefined even when they're clearly not, why does it do this and is there a way I can fix it?

In below example, the variable "Lot" is imported and is not undefined as is demonstrated by the result of the console.log line, however when I manually type in "Lot" in the debugger it says it's undefined.

[Screenshot with debugger and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z90OE.png)

Code from example:

```
import Lot from '../db/models/Lot'

console.log(Lot === undefined) // prints false
console.log("break") // Debugger stopped at this breakpoint shows Lot as undefined
```

If I assign Lot to a local variable then it works:

```
const Lot2 = Lot
console.log("break") // Debugger stopped at this breakpoint shows Lot2 as defined
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I also see this exact behaviour, I had it with some other variables too in my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65932801/error-object-in-vue-async-catch-block-is-undefined-in-debugger

Comment: Nope, sorry. I just use the hack I described above if I know I need access to an import while debugging, i.e. I assign it to a local variable.

Answer (score 6):

I found out something about this: in the `Closure` section of the debugger window, you should find your imported module has `_1` after its name, then you would access it with `Lot_1.Lot`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078164/debug-angular-typescript-in-visual-code-appends-1-to-variable) suggests that this happens when the `compilerOptions` is below `ES6`

Comment: Ahh thank you, that was a great help. For me, `import { Instance } from …` landed within the Closure section as `_instance.Instance`. (we're using knex among other things in my app).

ie. Prefixed with an underscore, and lowercased at the start (rather than adding `_1` after the name)